# Acces list from another class C#

Tags: c#, list, class, reference

I'm trying to access a list "newklädDataList" from another class by making a object out of the class and accessing a public method where i have implemented to return the list "newklädDataList" but it itsn't working; what's wrong here?

**This is the class where my list is:**

```
public class klädDATALIST //Kläddata sparas här
{

    private static List<klädDATALIST> newklädDataList = new List<klädDATALIST>(); // Lista med klädegenskaper

    public List<klädDATALIST> GetList() // Metod för att hämta lista
    {
        return newklädDataList;
    }

    public string märke;
    public string typ;
    public string färg; 
    public string storlek;        

    public klädDATALIST(string _märke, string _typ, string _färg, string _storlek) //Överlagrad konstruktor
    {
        this.märke = _märke;
        this.typ = _typ;
        this.färg = _färg;
        this.storlek = _storlek;            
    }
}
```

**And this is the class and method where i'm trying to access it:**

```
 public class menuVAL //Val av menu sker inom denna klass
{
    //public static List<klädDATALIST> newklädDataList = new List<klädDATALIST>();

    klädDATALIST h = new klädDATALIST();

    public void GetList()   
    {
        List<klädDATALIST> newklädDataList = h.GetList();

    }

    public static void laddaBASgarderob()
    {

        StreamReader infil = new StreamReader("BasGarderob.txt");
        string line;
        while ((line = infil.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] plagg = line.Split('\t');
            newklädDataList.Add(new klädDATALIST(plagg[0], plagg[1], plagg[2], plagg[3]));
        }

        infil.Close();


    }
```

}

**Thank you for your time!**

Comment: Elaborate on "isn't working". I think this could be a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class design is "interesting", but anyway, what you probably doing wrong is calling this:

```
klädDATALIST h = new klädDATALIST();
```

when you do not have parameterless constructor on klädDATALIST class.

So either implement a parameterless constructor:

```
public klädDATALIST() {}
```

OR make GetList static:

```
public static List<klädDATALIST> GetList() // Metod för att hämta lista
```

and in menuVAL.GetList call it like this:

```
List<klädDATALIST> newklädDataList = klädDATALIST.GetList();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it was just what i was looking for!

Comment: haha by the way, this is my first real project in programming. How would you improve my class design?

Comment: Absolutely the first thing that hit me (actually, not about the design) was using non-English language for naming classes/variables. Code in English, document in English, always. Now back to the design - you seem not to understand well the concept of "static" - static class, static variables. You mix static and non-static. You should use static when you want the thing to exist once in the application. You originally had `private static List<klädDATALIST> newklädDataList` in a non-static class, which means that no matter how many times you create an instance of that class, ...

Comment: ... this list will exists only once and will not be a part of each new instance. From your code, it is not clear, what was your intention, so it is hard to say, how it should be done properly. But a good advice for you is to try to find more information about what static means, what is static variable, what is static class, how does static variable work in a static class and how does it work in a non-static class. After you understand that concept, go back to your original code and you should see that it was kind of strange.